# How can I access the raw data of a drive from within vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, disk, hard-drive

How can I access the raw data of a drive in vb.net? I plan on making a filesystem, but I need raw disk access.

I'm meaning something like this:

```
Dim data(255) As Byte
data = ReadSector("C:", 5)
data(125) = asc("h")
data(126) = asc("e")
data(127) = asc("l")
data(128) = asc("l")
data(129) = asc("o")
WriteSector("C:", 5, data)
```

Where ReadSector has the arguments (drive As String, sector As Long) and WriteSector has (drive As String, sector As Long, data() As Byte).

This would write "hello" on the 126th character of the 5th sector on drive C.

Comment: I don't believe you can without a lower-level driver.  If you wish to make a filesystem, you should make a driver.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx

Comment: @Brad I still need raw disk access for other things. The best for me would be to use vb.net, or at the very least, C that is embedded into vb.net, but if that is impossible, then I can probably learn C. I'd like to leave this as a last resort though.

Comment: I'm not certain how to access the drive directly in this manner, but I'm fairly confident you'll need to use the `IOCTL` interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363147%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

What OS, this matters because after windows 95 direct disk access was removed from the programs. You could build a module outside of vb and link to it maybe.